# CSS - Text aligns with text in other div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website with a display like the one presented in the code. One issue I keep running into is that as seen in the example, the "`Sweep`" text keeps aligning with the "`Select Campaign:`" text from the `side_panel_left` div. I would like it to appear at the very top of its own div instead. An example can be seen with the "Run code snippet".

I tried changing the display of the `side_panel_right` div to see if that would change things, however it seems that whether it is block or table-cell, the text still aligns with `"Select Campaign:"`.

What is the reasoning behind this? Is there any way I can override this behaviour, and just get `"Sweep"` to appear at the top of the `side_panel_right`?

```css
#app_container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#side_panel_left {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 240px;
}

.panel {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}

.input_title {
    position: relative;
    left: 5%;
}

.input_element {
    display: block;
    margin: 8px;
}

.input_box {
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    left: 40%;
}

.trigger_buttons {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.run_reset_buttons {
    float: left;
    width: calc(50% - 2px);
}

#map {
    display: table-cell;
}

#side_panel_right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app_container">
        <br>
        <div id="side_panel_left">
            <div id="campaign_select" class="panel">
                <span class="input_element input_title">Select Campaign:</span>
                <select id="campaign_drop" class="input_element input_box"></select>
            </div>
            <div id="numerical_input" class="panel">

            </div>
            <div id="run" class="trigger_buttons run_reset_buttons panel">
                Run
            </div>
            <div id="reset" class="trigger_buttons run_reset_buttons panel">
                Reset
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="map" class="panel">

        </div>
        <div id="side_panel_right">
            <div id="sweep">
                Sweep
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: which position sweep button you want to set? can you show demo image?

Comment: i dont really understand what you are trying to do.. could you provide a sketch?

Comment: Sweep does appear at the top of the side panel right div, perhaps you need to add `vertical-align: top` to `#side_panel_right` to get rid of that small bit of padding but other than that I don't understand what you are after

Comment: @J.Sadi If you run the code snippet, it shows that Sweep is vertically aligned with Select Campaign:. I don't want this, I just want Sweep to be at the top of it's div. I'll edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: @Pete thanks that was exactly what it needed, that was all I was getting at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to `#side_panel_right`

```
#side_panel_right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 140px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```